# Exceptions and WCF services with void return type

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

If we call a WCF service with a void as a return type.

Will it wait around for the service to finish processing in case there is an exception?

Or will it return imediately and the client will not be notified of any exception on the server?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default it will wait around. If you use the **IsOneWay** attribute however, it will not.

Answer (score 3):

The execution of a WCF method will not become asynchronous just because there is a `void` return type.  It will still execute to completion before returning.